# Sorting blocks in matrix Java

Tags: java, sorting, matrix, row, columnsorting

Given an N^2 X N^2 matrix, which is divided to NxN blocks, I need to sort them from left to right, top to bottom.

for example:

```
int[][] matrix1 =  {{11,12,13,14},
                            {15,16,17,18},
                            {19,20,21,22},
                            {23,24,25,26}} ;

    int[][] sortedBlock= {{11, 12, 15, 16}, 
                       {13, 14, 17, 18}, 
                       {19, 20, 23, 24}, 
                       {21, 22, 25, 26}} ; 

    int[][] matBlocks1 = TasksArrays.blocks (matrix1, 2) ;
```

note how it goes from 11,12 then down for 13,14 ect.
the 2 in the (matrix1,2) says how many number are there to be in the row and column of each block, in short it represents the 'n' in the NxN block.

my first line of code must be:

```
 public static int[][] blocks (int[][] matrix, int sqrtN)
```

I've tried to define another function to assist me (min index), but I'm not so sure it will know to go from block to block..
here is what I've come up with, **if you believe its irrelevant, then don't use**:

```
public static int minIndex (int [][] array , int row, int col) {                       
     int min= array[row][col];                                                         
    for (int i = row; i <array.length; i++ )      {                                    
        for ( int j = col; j < array[0].length; j++) {                                 
            if (array[row][col]<min){                                                  
                min=array[row][col];                                                   
            }                                                                          
        }                                                                              
    }                                                                                  
    return min;                                                                        
}
```

Comment: where is the code for blocks??? we aren't going to do your homework for you...

Comment: Are you in the same school with the author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563710/java-2d-array-swap-into-blocks)?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I don't know how to address the matrix as blocks, thats my problem... I get how to sort them but not as block and how to tell the function that by entering sqrtN, it needs to stop checking and start sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting it the way described above can be achieved by the following algorithm:

1. "flat" the matrix into one long array, in our case: {11,12,13,14, 15,16,17,18...
2. Sort the array using your favorite algorithm, I'd recommend using `Arrays.sort()`
3. copy the (now sorted) flattened array back into the original matrix, this part is a bit tricky because you need to think how to map an item in the flattened array back into the original matrix, but if you'll play with 2-3 examples and do it manually you can figure out the formula